# How to edit jade image field from within Node/Express?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I want to display an image on a webpage on the basis of what the user enters in a form. I have the form defined in abc.jade, and in abc.js I store everything from the form, and generate the image's url and store it in a variable map_img on the basis of the form. How do I set an image's source in jade to point to map_img URL?

abc.js:

```
sales.save();
markers = [{ 'location': sales.location }]
var gm = require('googlemaps');
var map_img = gm.staticMap(sales.location, 16, '500x400', false, false, markers);
```

In general, what is the best way to manipulate fields in an HTML/Jade document from node/express?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure if i get your question right...

There are severals ways to send data. 
Mostly described here: http://jade-lang.com/reference/

I usually use #{img_map} or in the case you have to get pure html its better to use !{img_map_html_desc}.

Also, the alternative variant, create #temp div, send data there. Than on the front end js(on window.onload) you can get that data and store to the variable. Don't forget to clear the #temp div after you dont need that anymore.
Once i've used side front-end js module and couldnt find better sollution, than this. Cause that module waited for window.onload, and than started to load itself...